# Events Only in Model of MVVM WPF Architecutre

Tags: wpf, mvvm, eventaggregator

I have request by my leadership to consolidate events in a centralized place.

This is the story.....

We implemented an architecture, where we are developing a system as components (say one of the component is Grid and other is a Tree). Each of these components will be built using MVVM design pattern with Model being common for both the said component.

Hope you are with me still....

Reason for each component separate is that we can work with independent components and marry such component on need basis in a project. Say we have a scenario where we want to use Grid and Tree component in a project.

And there is a need to communicate between the components using events. We have 2 school of thoughts (both uses event aggregator)

School a) 
VM of the each component will raise and consume the events. Model will have data and some business logic in it. (obvious property change events are included in model).

School b) 
Let us have all events raising centralized in Model. Model raises the event, which is consumed by VM as required.

Any thoughts on which one is better?

Comment: this is a broad question which will result in a debate on the mvvm patter and its uses, I would suggest creating a relevant small example of the events and their handling

Comment: Sorry Makc... Small example of the events and their handling... Do you mean what types of events I am alluding to here or what types of events will the 2 components work with?

Comment: If I assumption about your question is correct then say the user wants to drag a node from the tree and drop on the grid. There need to be a communication happening between the 2 components that a node was dropped from tree on grid.. Additionally the model will have its data modified as well

Answer (score 0):

First one is better because in this thought you are pretty much stick to mvvm pattern and when your project becomes bigger it is easy for you check the issues for a particular component in corresponding viewmodels. it will be easy to manage then.

Comment: If we have it in Model, it is a single place (which is common across the components) where we know all the events that will be utilizied by all the VM's (consumption of the event).

Comment: model basically the data part of mvvm for logic implementation you should use vm and for communication you can also use messenger class of mvvm.the problem what i am thinking of is when your project becomes bigger the first aproach would be better.you can track the issue in better way.

Comment: Can you provide specific items that you think will help us in larger project.

Comment: Even if you have a link that would help us

Comment: actually this mvvm pattern is oriented to larget projects. And mvvm pattern does not mean that you can't do anything in page.xaml.cs you can work in this class for your UI but for your logic part implement them in viewmodels. And properly define your viewmodel for which page it is. and page and viewmodel should be one entity. so when your your work becomes larger then you can treat this entity as an object so it is easy for you to manage. in the end just try to stuck to this pattern and if you got any problem just post it here i will surely help you out any how